# knockout: Binding observable array to click binding does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, lodash

If I want to remove an element in an observable array from the view, I might do something like this..

```
<div data-bind="foreach: records">
   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked, click: $parent.removeRow">
</div>
```

then in my viewModel....

```
this.removeRow = function(item) { this.records.remove(item); }
```

that works as expected.

However, I figured that was an extra step, why not try

```
click: $parent.records.remove
```

thinking that `$data` would be passed to remove. That doesn't work and I get `Uncaught TypeError: this.peek is not a function`

I thought maybe because the event was being passed as a second parameter, that might be causing problems with `remove()`, so I tried:

```
click: _.unary($parent.records.remove)
```

_.unary returns a function that only takes one parameter. This didn't work either and I got the same peek error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work because `this` won't be the `records` array when the `click` binding invokes the `remove` method.

You can fix this with using bind:

```
click: $parent.records.remove.bind($parent.records)
```

In my opinion your original solution with the dedicated `removeRow` function on your view model is a cleaner solution.